# Error while install-info processing in apache2 installation

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I removed apache on ubuntu 12.04 using following command

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2*
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2
```

But while removing apache 2 I got following error:

```
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
Errors were encountered while processing:
install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**
```

Please Help me...

Comment: you should ask this at http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem during an UPGRADE.

**install-info** rebuilds the "info" database by calling **update-info-dir** which in turn tries to find out the default system language installed by the user. In order to switch to the system's default language, **update-info-dir** executes `/env/environment`. This is what my environment file looks like and the first line is different for everybody depending on what's installed.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/mysql/server-5.6/bin"
source /etc/environment
```

Note the 2nd line. `/etc/environment` is calling itself! That's not good.

Simply comment out/delete `source /etc/environment` and try again.